# Import pdal error on windows 10 (JSONDecodeError)

Tags: python, jsondecoder, pdal

Have some problem with PDAL lib. After the library installation tried to `import pdal` and the error has been rised:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17208/3968280360.py in <module>
----> 1 import pdal

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdal\__init__.py in <module>
      6 from .pipeline import Filter, Pipeline, Reader, Stage, Writer
      7 
----> 8 inject_pdal_drivers()
      9 dimensions = libpdalpython.getDimensions()
     10 info = libpdalpython.getInfo()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdal\drivers.py in inject_pdal_drivers()
     68 #     options = libpdalpython.getOptions()
     69 
---> 70     drivers = json.loads(
     71         subprocess.run(["pdal", "--drivers", "--showjson"], capture_output=True).stdout
     72     )

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    344             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:
    348         cls = JSONDecoder

~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    351         """
    352         try:
--> 353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
    355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 759 column 17 (char 25323)
```

I've tried to decompose the problem and used the next:

```
import subprocess
import json

subproc = subprocess.run(["pdal", "--drivers", "--showjson"], capture_output=True).stdout    
drivers = json.loads(subproc)
```

and found that `subprocess.run(["pdal", "--drivers", "--showjson"])` completed with an error returncode `CompletedProcess(args=['pdal', '--drivers', '--showjson'], returncode=3221226505)` and .stdout of this subprocess gets incompleted .json file (the code below is **tail-6** of `subprocess.run(["pdal", "--drivers", "--showjson"], capture_output=True).stdout` and it's unfinished).

```
{
    "description": "Write data in the Point Cloud Library (PCL) format.",
    "extensions": [
        "pcd"
    ],
    "link": "http://pda
```

Did anyone meet such problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a conda installation of PDAL 2.2.0 on a pre-existing conda environment (Windows 10, Python 3.9)

Then, as suggested [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-pdal-feedstock/issues/2) I reinstalled PDAL on a new dedicated environment
with:

```
conda create -n <environment name> -c conda-forge python-pdal
```

and

```
python import pdal
```

is now working.

Here is the .yml file content of the environment that was creting the problem in the first place :

```
name: geo_env2
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - abseil-cpp=20210324.1=h0e60522_0
  - affine=2.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - altair=4.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - appdirs=1.4.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - arrow-cpp=4.0.0=py39h55b1ac3_3_cpu
  - astropy=5.1=py39h5d4886f_0
  - asttokens=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - async_generator=1.10=py_0
  - attrs=22.1.0=pyh71513ae_1
  - aws-c-cal=0.5.11=he19cf47_0
  - aws-c-common=0.6.2=h8ffe710_0
  - aws-c-event-stream=0.2.7=h70e1b0c_13
  - aws-c-io=0.10.5=h2fe331c_0
  - aws-checksums=0.1.11=h1e232aa_7
  - aws-sdk-cpp=1.8.186=hb0612c5_3
  - backcall=0.2.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - backports=1.0=py_2
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - bcrypt=3.2.2=py39ha55989b_1
  - blinker=1.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - blosc=1.21.1=hcbbf2c4_0
  - bokeh=2.4.3=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - boost-cpp=1.74.0=h54f0996_3
  - branca=0.3.1=py_0
  - brotli=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - brotli-bin=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - brotlipy=0.7.0=py39hb82d6ee_1004
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h8ffe710_4
  - c-ares=1.18.1=h8ffe710_0
  - ca-certificates=2022.9.24=h5b45459_0
  - cachetools=5.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=hb19e0ff_1008
  - cartopy=0.19.0.post1=py39hfa2520c_1
  - certifi=2022.9.24=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cffi=1.15.1=py39h0878f49_0
  - cfitsio=3.470=h0af3d06_7
  - charls=2.2.0=h39d44d4_0
  - charset-normalizer=2.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - click=7.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - click-plugins=1.1.1=py_0
  - cligj=0.7.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - cloudpickle=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - commonmark=0.9.1=py_0
  - cryptography=37.0.4=py39h7bc7c5c_0
  - curl=7.83.1=h789b8ee_0
  - cycler=0.11.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - cytoolz=0.12.0=py39hb82d6ee_0
  - dask=2022.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dask-core=2022.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dask-geopandas=0.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - dataclasses=0.8=pyhc8e2a94_3
  - debugpy=1.6.3=py39h99910a6_1
  - decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - distributed=2022.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - earthpy=0.9.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - entrypoints=0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - executing=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - expat=2.4.8=h39d44d4_0
  - fiona=1.8.18=py39h9f1b043_1
  - folium=0.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - fontconfig=2.14.0=hce3cb01_0
  - fonttools=4.37.1=py39hb82d6ee_0
  - freetype=2.12.1=h546665d_0
  - freexl=1.0.6=ha8e266a_0
  - fsspec=2022.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - future=0.18.2=pyhd8ed1ab_6
  - gdal=3.2.1=py39h6795fcd_7
  - geckodriver=0.30.0=hdb13177_0
  - geopandas=0.11.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - geopandas-base=0.11.1=pyha770c72_0
  - geos=3.9.1=h39d44d4_2
  - geotiff=1.6.0=hee96dd5_4
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=ha2e2712_1008
  - gflags=2.2.2=ha925a31_1004
  - giflib=5.2.1=h8d14728_2
  - gitdb=4.0.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - gitpython=3.1.29=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - glog=0.5.0=h4797de2_0
  - grpc-cpp=1.37.1=h586195c_2
  - h11=0.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - hdf4=4.2.15=h0e5069d_4
  - hdf5=1.10.6=nompi_h5268f04_1114
  - heapdict=1.0.1=py_0
  - icu=68.2=h0e60522_0
  - idna=3.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - imagecodecs=2021.3.31=py39h433ed9d_0
  - imageio=2.13.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - importlib-metadata=4.11.4=py39hcbf5309_0
  - importlib_resources=5.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - intel-openmp=2022.1.0=h57928b3_3787
  - ipykernel=6.17.0=pyh025b116_0
  - ipython=8.6.0=pyh08f2357_1
  - ipywidgets=8.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - jedi=0.18.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - joblib=1.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jpeg=9e=h8ffe710_2
  - jsonschema=4.17.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_client=7.3.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jupyter_core=4.11.2=py39hcbf5309_0
  - jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - jxrlib=1.1=h8ffe710_2
  - kealib=1.4.14=h96bfa42_2
  - kiwisolver=1.4.4=py39h2e07f2f_0
  - krb5=1.19.3=h1176d77_0
  - laspy=2.2.0=pyh8a188c0_0
  - lcms2=2.12=h2a16943_0
  - lerc=2.2.1=h0e60522_0
  - libaec=1.0.6=h39d44d4_0
  - libblas=3.9.0=16_win64_mkl
  - libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h8ffe710_7
  - libcblas=3.9.0=16_win64_mkl
  - libcurl=7.83.1=h789b8ee_0
  - libdeflate=1.7=h8ffe710_5
  - libffi=3.4.2=h8ffe710_5
  - libgdal=3.2.1=hca2c63a_7
  - libglib=2.72.1=h3be07f2_0
  - libiconv=1.16=he774522_0
  - libkml=1.3.0=h9859afa_1014
  - liblapack=3.9.0=16_win64_mkl
  - libnetcdf=4.7.4=nompi_h3a9aa94_107
  - libpng=1.6.37=h1d00b33_4
  - libpq=13.5=hfcc5ef8_1
  - libprotobuf=3.16.0=h7755175_0
  - librttopo=1.1.0=hb340de5_6
  - libsodium=1.0.18=h8d14728_1
  - libspatialindex=1.9.3=h39d44d4_4
  - libspatialite=5.0.1=h987baeb_3
  - libsqlite=3.39.3=hcfcfb64_0
  - libssh2=1.10.0=h680486a_3
  - libthrift=0.14.1=h636ae23_2
  - libtiff=4.2.0=h763f289_2
  - libutf8proc=2.8.0=h82a8f57_0
  - libwebp-base=1.2.4=h8ffe710_0
  - libxml2=2.9.14=hf5bbc77_4
  - libzlib=1.2.12=h8ffe710_2
  - libzopfli=1.0.3=h0e60522_0
  - locket=1.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - lz4=4.0.0=py39h0878066_2
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h8ffe710_1
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
  - m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
  - m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - mapclassify=2.4.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - markupsafe=2.1.1=py39hb82d6ee_1
  - matplotlib-base=3.5.3=py39he03a255_2
  - matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - metpy=1.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - mkl=2022.1.0=h6a75c08_874
  - msgpack-python=1.0.4=py39h2e07f2f_0
  - msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
  - munch=2.5.0=py_0
  - munkres=1.1.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - nbformat=5.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - nest-asyncio=1.5.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - networkx=2.8.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - numpy=1.23.2=py39h1a62c8c_0
  - olefile=0.46=pyh9f0ad1d_1
  - openjpeg=2.4.0=hb211442_1
  - openssl=1.1.1s=hcfcfb64_0
  - outcome=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - packaging=21.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pandas=1.4.4=py39h80a8885_0
  - paramiko=2.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - parquet-cpp=1.5.1=2
  - parso=0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - partd=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pcre=8.45=h0e60522_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
  - pillow=8.2.0=py39h1a9d4f7_1
  - pint=0.19.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pip=22.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pixman=0.40.0=h8ffe710_0
  - pkgutil-resolve-name=1.3.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pooch=1.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - poppler=0.89.0=h3772339_5
  - poppler-data=0.4.11=hd8ed1ab_0
  - postgresql=13.5=h1c22c4f_1
  - proj=7.2.0=h1cfcee9_2
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.32=pyha770c72_0
  - protobuf=3.16.0=py39h415ef7b_0
  - psutil=5.9.2=py39ha55989b_0
  - pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyarrow=4.0.0=py39hf9247be_3_cpu
  - pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pydeck=0.7.1=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - pyerfa=2.0.0.1=py39h5d4886f_2
  - pygeos=0.10.2=py39haadaec5_0
  - pygments=2.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pykrige=1.7.0=py39hb82d6ee_0
  - pympler=1.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pynacl=1.5.0=py39h09fa780_2
  - pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyparsing=3.0.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pyrsistent=0.19.2=py39ha55989b_0
  - pysftp=0.2.9=py_1
  - pyshp=2.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pysocks=1.7.1=pyh0701188_6
  - python=3.9.13=h9a09f29_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-fastjsonschema=2.16.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python-tzdata=2022.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python_abi=3.9=2_cp39
  - pytz=2022.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pytz-deprecation-shim=0.1.0.post0=py39hcbf5309_3
  - pywavelets=1.3.0=py39h5d4886f_1
  - pywin32=304=py39h99910a6_2
  - pyyaml=6.0=py39hb82d6ee_4
  - pyzmq=24.0.1=py39hea35a22_1
  - rasterio=1.2.6=py39h334309b_0
  - re2=2021.04.01=h0e60522_0
  - requests=2.28.1=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - rich=12.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - rtree=1.0.0=py39h09fdee3_1
  - scikit-image=0.19.3=py39h2e25243_1
  - scikit-learn=1.1.2=py39hfd4428b_0
  - scipy=1.9.1=py39h316f440_0
  - selenium=4.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - semver=2.13.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - setuptools=65.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - shapely=1.8.0=py39haadaec5_0
  - six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
  - smmap=3.0.5=pyh44b312d_0
  - snappy=1.1.9=h82413e6_1
  - sniffio=1.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - snuggs=1.4.7=py_0
  - sortedcontainers=2.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sqlite=3.39.3=hcfcfb64_0
  - stack_data=0.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - streamlit=1.14.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tbb=2021.5.0=h2d74725_1
  - tblib=1.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - threadpoolctl=3.1.0=pyh8a188c0_0
  - tifffile=2021.4.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tiledb=2.2.9=hf84e3da_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h8ffe710_0
  - toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - toolz=0.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - tornado=6.1=py39hb82d6ee_3
  - traitlets=5.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - trio=0.21.0=py39hcbf5309_0
  - trio-websocket=0.9.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - typing_extensions=4.3.0=pyha770c72_0
  - tzdata=2022c=h191b570_0
  - tzlocal=4.2=py39hcbf5309_2
  - ucrt=10.0.20348.0=h57928b3_0
  - unicodedata2=14.0.0=py39hb82d6ee_1
  - urllib3=1.26.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - validators=0.18.2=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - vc=14.2=hb210afc_7
  - vs2015_runtime=14.29.30139=h890b9b1_7
  - watchdog=2.1.9=py39hcbf5309_1
  - wcwidth=0.2.5=pyh9f0ad1d_2
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - widgetsnbextension=4.0.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - win_inet_pton=1.1.0=py39hcbf5309_4
  - wsproto=1.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xarray=2022.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - xerces-c=3.2.3=h0e60522_5
  - xyzservices=2022.6.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xz=5.2.6=h8d14728_0
  - yaml=0.2.5=h8ffe710_2
  - zeromq=4.3.4=h0e60522_1
  - zfp=0.5.5=h0e60522_8
  - zict=2.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zipp=3.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - zlib=1.2.12=h8ffe710_2
  - zstd=1.4.9=h6255e5f_0
  - pip:
    - geographiclib==1.52
    - laszip==0.1.0
    - lazrs==0.4.4
    - pyproj==3.0.1
    - whitebox==1.0.1
prefix: C:\Anaconda3\envs\geo_env2
```